# Highlight (change background) / of the content in a web page dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Is there any way to change the `background-color` of text in a web page dynamically, while select the particular text.

Ex :

Sample text display in the html page. I want to **high light the particular text** in that page, while selecting from mouse pointer.

My Ground Work :

Add the class "CSS Style" for particular selected text. But how to take the selected text from a web page dynamically.

Comment: Check if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek Even this works only if know the selected content previously. My question is that user will select the content dynamically while reading the content in the web page. Only that content has to high lighted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could style the selected text dynamically using the CSS selector `::selection`.

```css
#content::selection {
  background-color: plum;
  color: white;
}
#content::-moz-selection {
  background-color: plum;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">Sample text display in the html page. I want to high light the particular text in that page, while selecting from mouse pointer.</div>
```

Comment: Ya this ok My question is how to take the selected content dynamically to replace.

Comment: In inner HTML you can take all the content of particular element. If i have selected only particular content how its work?

Comment: Ya your code works statically if know the selected content correct? What i am asking is that user will select the content dynamically while reading the content in the web page.

Comment: @RajavelD - Check out the update. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks chipChocolate.py Your codes sounds good. But if i selected second statement first selected content again changes to default one.

Comment: @RajavelD - To highlight more text you have to press and hold the Ctrl key and select the second text.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing is there any way to read the selected content by mouse?

Comment: @RajavelD - What do you intend to do with it?

Comment: In a web page i want to highlight the selected content by the user. Not using Ctrl key and all. Ex. in a tutorial if any impotent points the user want to highlight with there own session not for entire web site.

Comment: @RajavelD - For that you will have to use JavaScript. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text) are some solutions that will help you.

Comment: Thank you very much chipChocolat.py